# Guava cache removal not being triggered

Tags: scala, guava, cats-effect

I have a situation where some events I need to keep track of become "stale" after a specific timeout (`expiryTimeout`). Upon expiration, I need to "remove" references of the expired event, as well as notifying an external service that the event was expired. If, before the expiration, a more recent event for the same key is received, then the timeout is "reset" (e.g. the event is "refreshed"). No notification needs to be sent out in this case.

I am trying to use a Guava cache to achieve the above and to not reinvent the wheel, but I must be missing something, because the expiration does not seem to be triggered.

I have the following `IO` code to create the "cache":

```
abstract sealed case class StaleTasksCleanerWithGuava private(srvc: ExternalService,
                                                              expiryTimeout: FiniteDuration)
                                                             (implicit cs: ContextShift[IO], evictionEs: ExecutorService) {
  implicit val logger = Slf4jLogger.getLogger[IO]

  private val removalListener = new RemovalListener[Key, TaskEvent]() {
    override def onRemoval(rn: RemovalNotification[Key, TaskEvent]): Unit = {
      val f = if(rn.wasEvicted()){
        val (appId, taskId) = rn.getKey
        logger.debug(s"[$appId-$taskId] Expiring entry now...") *>
          srvc.cleanUpStaleTask(appId, taskId) *>
          logger.debug(s"[$appId-$taskId] Entry expired.")
      } else
        IO.unit

      f.unsafeRunSync() // Necessary because of the way Guava's API is designed
    }
  }

  private val asyncRemovalListener = RemovalListeners.asynchronous(removalListener, evictionEs)

  private val c: Cache[Key, TaskEvent] = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .expireAfterWrite(expiryTimeout.length, expiryTimeout.unit)
    .removalListener(asyncRemovalListener).build[Key, TaskEvent]()

  def putTask(e: TaskEvent): IO[Unit] = {
    val k = (e.appId, e.taskId)
    logger.debug(s"[${k._1}-${k._2}] Entry will expire in $expiryTimeout if not overridden.") *>
      IO(c.put(k, e))
  }
}

object StaleTasksCleanerWithGuava {
  type Key = (String, String)

  def create(srvc: ExternalService, expiryTimeout: FiniteDuration = 1.second)
            (implicit cs: ContextShift[IO], evictionEs: ExecutorService): IO[StaleTasksCleanerWithGuava] = {
    IO(new StaleTasksCleanerWithGuava(srvc, expiryTimeout) {})
  }
}
```

The most notable thing from this is that I am using an `val asyncRemovalListener = RemovalListeners.asynchronous(removalListener, evictionEs)` to ensure that the expiration and removals are done asynchronously, and not as part of other cache operations (reads/writes).

I created the following example app to test simply things:

```
object TestAppWithGuava2 extends IOApp {
  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    implicit val logger = Slf4jLogger.getLogger[IO]

    val dummy = new ExternalService {
      override def cleanUpStaleTask(appId: String, taskId: String): IO[Unit] =
        logger.debug(s"[Service - ${appId}-${taskId}] Notified! +1")
    }
    val taskEvent1 = TaskEvent("A", "task1")
    val taskEvent2 = TaskEvent("B", "task2")
    val taskEvent3 = TaskEvent("C", "task1")

    val evictionEcResource = Resource.make(IO{Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8)})(tp => IO(tp.shutdownNow()).void)

    val program = evictionEcResource.use{ evictionEc =>
      for {
        cache <- StaleTasksCleanerWithGuava.create(dummy, 3.second)(contextShift, evictionEc)
        _ <- cache.putTask(taskEvent3)
        _ <- cache.putTask(taskEvent1)
        _ <- cache.putTask(taskEvent2)
        _ <- IO.never  /// This is here on purpose, as I want to see things being expired
      } yield ()
    }
    IO.race(program, IO.sleep(6.seconds)).as(ExitCode.Success)
  }
}
```

However this miserably fails to do what I expect it to do. :)
When I run this, I get these log lines and, after few seconds of nothing, the application terminates (as `IO.sleep(6.seconds)` terminates and "wins" the `race`).

```
2020-03-01 18:48:41,862 [StaleTasksCleanerWithGuava] [C-task1] Entry will expire in 3 seconds if not overridden.
2020-03-01 18:48:41,874 [StaleTasksCleanerWithGuava] [A-task1] Entry will expire in 3 seconds if not overridden.
2020-03-01 18:48:41,874 [StaleTasksCleanerWithGuava] [B-task2] Entry will expire in 3 seconds if not overridden.
```

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Guava performs expiration on calling threads, so nothing occurs until the next access. You could use [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Cleanup) with a configured `scheduler` which will perform the work on a background thread.

Comment: But isn't the asynchronous listener supposed to do exactly that? Using a separate Executor to run the listeners?

Comment: But what thread notifies the listener?

Comment: I see, that makes sense. However, even when I add further cache activity (e.g. `_ <- IO.sleep(4.seconds) *> cache.putTask(taskEvent2)`) some tasks are never expired, like `C-task1`, while others are (`A-task1` and `B-task2`). I seem to still be missing something.

Comment: Actually, I found that triggering a `cleanUp` on the cache does trigger expiration of  `C` but `put`ting for some other key does not...

Comment: That is because guava splits into multiple caches, based on the concurrencyLevel (defaulted to 4). So activity on the segment is required to trigger a cleanup automatically.